# Camel appears to ignore onException instruction - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel (2.21.2) route that gets an XML file via FTP and then splits it before processing further, somewhat like...

```
from("direct-vm:start")
    .split()
    .xtokenize("*/row", 'w', ns)
    .streaming()
    ...
```

If an empty file is passed, I am getting a `com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException` raised by the xtokenize step I presume, which seems perfectly reasonable.

However, when I try to put in an `onException` clause, it doesn't seem to be catching the exception.

I have:

```
onException(com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException.class)
    .handled(true)
    .log(org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel.INFO,
        "myLogger",
        "File ${header.CamelFileName} is empty or invalid XML");
```

and yet the exception is resulting in the route failing with the exception, and my handler log message is never produced.

However, if I change the `onException` clause to `java.lang.Exception.class`, it does handle the exception.

I don't want this to handle any exception, just the one caused by an empty or incomplete file.

What I am doing wrong here? How do I get `onException` to handle only the exception I am interested in?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Assuming the class is correct the order of the `OnException` is important and might be the cause, check: https://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html `How Does Camel Select Which Clause Should Handle a Given Thrown Exception?`

Comment: Do you really have multiple Camel contexts running and need `direct-vm` in first place? If so, is your exception handler defined in a different context than the route that is throwing the exception? If so the [default exception handler of that route might still be in place](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/OnException-across-camelcontext-not-called-when-using-direct-vm-td5789237.html) which might prevent the exception from being propagated to your exception handler running in a different context